Expo router, acceder al manifest/permisos para denegar aplicaciones instaladas
tengo una duda acerca de como validar aplicaciones instaladas en tu dispositivo median expo router, la idea o en teoria lo que buscaba era poder tener acceso al androidManifest.xml y poder agregar las aplicaciones que no se permiten estar instaladas en el dispositivo por x o y motivo en este caso son aplicaciones de gps fake, pero al no tener acceso a ese archivo quisiera ver si existe alguna alternativa, ya que si uso librerias de terceros la play store no me permite subir mi app por esa razon de que uso aplicaciones de terceros y tengo que justificar el porque pero las veces que lo he echo me niegan la subida de mi app.
agradeceria si pudieran guiarme o si hay alguna posible solucion a ese problema.
